# Best way to load a lot of embed elements in HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, video, embed, rtsp

I want to show several embed elements in my website. They show a rtsp files (video), so when I load a lot of them, the site is very very slow, obviously. 
 
I did it in two different ways, but none of them didn't give me a good result:

1. **Only one embed element, every 20s its content change with another element with other url**. You should know that the target attribute can't be updated because the embed element doesn't reload. So the only way to do this is replacing the entire element. **The problem with this is the load, when I replace the element, it takes like 10s to appear the video**.

> ```
> <embed id="video" class="video" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="player" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="yes" loop="yes" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" fullscreen target="rtsp://xxxxxxxx"></embed>
> ```

```
function cambiarCanal() {
    var objeto = '<embed id="video" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="player" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="yes" loop="yes" target="'+canales[3]+'"></embed>';
    $("#video").replaceWith(objeto);

    /* cambiar cada 20s el canal del video */
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
         cambiarCanal();
    }, 20000);
}
```

2. **Make a slider/carousel with jQuery or just CSS3 to show all the embed elements previously loaded**. **The problem with this is slowness**, too much slowness. I have tasted like twenty sliders differents, just jQuery or just CSS3, but they are so slow and the server becomes saturated.

I tried with 'embed' and 'object' elements, same result.

So, is there any way to load twenty embed elements, and show one after other like a carousel without slowness? Maybe knowing if the next element has already been loaded and change it to the current one?

Comment: My best bet is to drop the `autoplay="yes"` and use script to start play, and done like that, as soon as the first have been loaded and you start it to play, you load the second, and when it is time to shift, you start nr 2, close/delete nr 1 and load nr 3, and so on...

Comment: @LGSon Hi, it's a good solution, I'm trying to do that but I can't change the autoplay attribute with jQuery, I don't know why. I have tried with `.attr("autoplay", "yes")`, and with value 1; `.trigger("autoplay")`; `.autoplay`... And it doesn't change...

Comment: If you try to make it play by adding the attribute `autoplay="yes"` on an already loaded player won't work, you'll need to use a `play()` command, which you will find in the docs for the given player

Comment: @LGSon Thanks!! I get it! It was with `.playlist.play()`. Using the VLC plugin, the only way to play the video is using **playlist**